# Manipulate and Initialization with functions and some variables

Tags: functions, manipulate, initialization

I am trying to do a manipulate with a function that depends on several variables, some of which are also functions. I can't get it to work. I have tried including an "Initialization" but it only accepts a function with a single variable. For example, if I build the following manipulate, it works:

[image]

However, if A now depends on two variables, "v" and "q", then it doesn't work.

[image]

How could I do it? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please post actual, copyable input code instead of images of code!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a = 2 v q;

Manipulate[Plot[f[v, q], {x, 14, 17}],
 {{v, 1}, 0.5, 9, 0.1}, {{q, 1}, 1, 15, 0.1},
 Initialization :> {f[v_, q_] = a x}]
```

Or simpler:

```
Manipulate[
 a = 2 v q;
 Plot[a x, {x, 14, 17}],
 {{v, 1}, 0.5, 9, 0.1}, {{q, 1}, 1, 15, 0.1}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel. And if now for example q were a function of another variable, in initizalitazion I should put all the variables.

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: Now, v and q are functions of b and c, respectivelly.     a = 2 v q;
v = 3 + b
q = 2 c;

Manipulate[
 Plot[f[b, c], {x, 14, 17}], {{b, 1}, 0.5, 9, 0.1}, {{c, 1}, 1, 15, 
  0.1}, Initialization :> {f[c_, b_] = a*x}]

Comment: `3 + b q = 2 c;` is a syntax error. Do you mean: `v= 2 c` ? Further, if "v and q are functions of b and c"  you should specify: v=.., c=..

Comment: Sorry, I want write that a = 2 v*q; v = 3 + b; q = 2* c; a is a function of v and q. On the other hand, v is function of b and q is function of c. I have probe the code that I indicated you before and it work.

Comment: b and c are not defined. If you give b and c a value, then you will get a plot.

Comment: Yes. I want obtain a plot with b and c as variables. I have incluied plot inside of manipulate.

Comment: If you want a plot with b and c as variables, you need e.g.  `Plot3D`. I you have further questions, you should include an example.

Comment: The plot is f as function as a. If the plot is respect b and c, then I need Plot3D as you say. Thank for your help.